# Need help for one table with different relationship in id

Tags: laravel-filament

[enter image description [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdL6g.png)here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StmT2.png)

How to add data in single resource with multiple models, hope you can answer my question, i want in Salary grade resource to input name,step and values but different id.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, code, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)